# Show that the vector of ones, e, is an eigenvector of the Google matrix transpose

Tags: page-rank

In the Google matrix where 
$$G=\alpha A+(1-\alpha)\frac{1}{n}ee^T$$

and $e$ is a vector of ones, how do I show that $e$ is the eigenvector of $G^T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue of 1

I need to show that $G^Te=e$ right?

I get $G^Te=(\alpha A^T+(1-\alpha)\frac{1}{n}e^Te)e$, not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: If $e^T = (1,\ldots,1) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $e^Te = n$;

$\ G^T e = (\alpha A^T + (1-\alpha))e = e \iff A^Te = e$

Comment: But the same missing step is $(\alpha A^T+(1-\alpha))e = e$, right?

Comment: isn't $A^T$ the normalized adjacency matrix?